# How to Change Feet and Inches Object Type Data Frame to Inches: Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data frames containing Height data like this

[image]

How to change into inches with dtype:float ?
thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Heigth_inches"] = (df.Height.str.split("'").str[0].astype(int) * 12) + (
    df.Height.str.split("'").str[1].astype(int)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Height  Heigth_inches
0    5'7             67
1    6'2             74
2    5'9             69
3   5'11             71
4   5'10             70
```

---

EDIT: Changed the computation, thanks @Serge

Comment: Thanyou for your answer, and how exactly if i want to change it to integer with rounding ? i have tried astype(int) it didnt work

Comment: AFAIK, 5'7 is 5 feet and 7 inches, said differently 67 inches and not 68.40 ...

Comment: @AdikaBagaskoro I've changed the computation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom converter here. Not that hard and you just have to build it carefully step by step:

1. split the input string on the comma. If it matters accept values like `6'` as 72 inches or `7` as 7 inches.
2. convert each element to integers (i.e. a integer number of feet and an integer number of inches (0<=x<12)
3. compute the total number of inches

In Python it could be:

```
def to_inches(h):
    l = [0 if i == '' else int(i) for i in h.split("'")]
    if len(l) == 0:
        return 0
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    return 12 * l[0] + l[1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> h = ["5'7", "6'2", "6", "7'", "0", '']
>>> [to_inches(i) for i in h]
[67, 74, 6, 84, 0, 0]
```